# Winpe how to create a Botable Windows PE RAM Disk for VmWare Virtual Machine

Tags: hard-drive, boot, virtual-machine, esxi, winpe

I'm trying to create a bootable WinPE RAM disk from Hard disk Drive for VMWare Virtual Machine.

I've seen that Microsoft has this method

```
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive
```

This method creates a bootable VHDx disk, and WinPE is loaded as RAM disk. And it allows me to reformat/manipulate the hard disk after boot, usually disk 0 and perform a clean Windows setup directly on disk.

To create it, I've attached a new disk on an existing Virtual Machine, I've initialized as MBR and then I've followed Microsoft steps on this mounted disk without error and I've detached it.

With this new disk, I've created a new Virtual machine and I've tried to boot without success.
I've tested with Bios/EFI options but it doesn't work, it doesn't boot

As a workaround, I've created a new bootable disk on a VHDX under a Hyper-V host and then I've used VMWare converter to upload to VMWare. The new converted machine worked every time I've tested.

Additionally, I've compared my VMWare disk with the disk that was created with VMware converter to understand if there is any difference, but apparently are identical, same files, identical attributes.

How can I create a bootable Winpe RAMdisk for VMWare without using the converter trick?

Comment: Write the WinPE to the physical drive of your choice, within VMWare, attatch that drive to the VM.  This will allow you to boot to the USB drive.  This is the only way to boot to a USB drive with VMWare.

Comment: I want to boot from the new 'vmdk' that contains Winpe Files, I don't want to boot from USB. I don't have access to USB drives, as my VmWare is running on ESX.

Comment: You tagged your question with the VMWare Player tag.  I went ahead and fixed the numerous grammatical mistakes I saw and fixed the tag usage for you.